# What is "Custom Program Error 0xa7" in anchor?

Tags: anchor, solana, anchor-solana

My Anchor program is giving me a `Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 1: custom program error: 0xa7` with nothing useful in the logs.

How do I even begin to debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom Program Error 0xa7 is `Error: 167: The given account is not owned by the executing program.`

This might happen if you pass in an account that's expected to be owned by a program, but isn't.

This can happen accidentally if you forget to set `declare_id!(/* ... */)` to the program id you're trying to hit.

Consider logging the program id that you're using in your javascript client:

```
console.log(program.programId)
```

And then seeing if that matches the public key that's in your `target/idl/yourprogram.json` file.

Comment: here's some query on this, see issues and code https://github.com/search?q=%22given+account+is+not+owned+by+the+executing+program%22+solana&type=issues

Comment: where did you lookup the error codes?

Comment: @BennoDev The 'custom program error' comes from the file `error.rs` in whatever the program is.